# Can I run a DDR4 module at 50 MHz?

Tags: protocol, ddr

I haven't seen any restrictions about minimum clock, but I may have overlooked them.

EDIT:
The module is a Crucial CT4G4SFS824A, based (this is an informed guess) on  [4Gb Micron 512 Meg x 8](http://(micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/%E2%80%A6)%20%E2%80%93)

Comment: What do you hope to learn from this "inspection"?  Likely you should consider some sort of simulation with a good model of behavior, instead of doing this physically in a setting where, even if it works, the kinds of physical limitations such as delays that would normally be a key concern will be all but invisible.

Comment: @ChrisStratton We are having problems with a custom board that fails on the write latency adjustment step. We'd like to inspect that specific calibration.

Comment: Please supply a part number of the module.  Looking at the part numbers of the chips themselves may be useful.  Any dynamic RAM has a minimum refresh rate; in the way-back (almost 20 years ago!!!) that worked out to a minimum clock of 100MHz or so on some parts we had been working with.

Comment: @TimWescott The module is a Crucial CT4G4SFS824A, based (this is an informed guess) on 4Gb Micron 512 Meg x 8 (https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/ddr4/4gb_ddr4_sdram.pdf)

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but Stackexchange wants you to answer such questions by editing your question, so they can have a tidy question/answer pair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but adjust the refresh rate accordingly to make sure you hit all the rows in the time specified in the datasheet. I’ve done this for FPGA ASIC prototyping and it works fine.